# Problem to associate test cases with test plan

Tags: visual-studio, github, azure-devops, test-plan

Recently I had to migrate an automation project from a azure TFS on-prem to an azure on cloud services. Our company decide to not use Azure Git repositories, instead they adopted the need of using a GitHub as our primary repository manager.

To associate a test case with a test plan before I just had to connect with the tfs server, select the repository I want and then download the project I needed to work, by doing that after I have my tests created on my test plan, and on my visual studio project, I just needed to open my test explorer select the test I want and associate by using a test id with the test on my test plan.

By now as we're using a GitHub repository and even we already integrated the github with our Azure, when I want to clone the repository I can't go through the new azure services to download the repository I have to go through a GitHub connection directly. The problem is by doing that I don't have a direct "connection" with the Azure servers on manage connection options. Because of that as I'm not connected to Azure Services or Azure TFS I can't associate my test cases with any of the test cases present on the azure test plan.

If you have any tips on how I can associate test cases from a github project with an azure devops test plan I'll really appreciate.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to associate test cases with a test plan in Azure DevOps you will have to have the test cases in DevOps. If you are storing them in GitHub then they aren't actually in DevOps. You could write automation with the REST library to create test cases in DevOps based on the cases you have stored in GitHub.

If you already have a copy of the test cases in DevOps and are just struggling to get results into DevOps then you could also write automation to do this.

Without knowing exactly what you are trying to accomplish it is hard to provide any detailed instructions on how to accomplish this. If you clarify your request some more then I might be able to provide more actionable feedback